# Basic applescripting - reading multiple files within folder

Tags: applescript

I've been trying to find something that explains how to read multiple files in applescript but I can only find ones that read 1 file.

- read all text files (.js, .json, .css, etc) within a folder
- verify each has a specific copyright (e.g. "© 2013 copyright. All rights reserved.")
- create a new document that lists the file and whether the copyright is correct for each.

e.g.

- particleTrail.js  - PASS
- blur.js           - PASS
- canvasParticle.js - FAIL
- etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
set output to ""

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (get files of (get POSIX file "/Users/username/Folder" as alias))
        if (read (f as alias) as «class utf8») contains "© 2013 copyright" then
            set output to output & name of f & " - PASS" & linefeed
        else
            set output to output & name of f & " - FAIL" & linefeed
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

set b to open for access "/Users/username/Desktop/output.txt" with write permission
set eof b to 0
write output to b as «class utf8»
close access b
```

If `as «class utf8»` is left out, `read` and `write` use the primary encoding, like MacRoman or MacJapanese. `Unicode text` is UTF-16.

Or using shell scripting:

`for f in ~/Folder/*; do grep -q '© 2013 copyright' "$f" && x=PASS || x=FAIL; echo "${f##*/} - $x"; done > ~/Desktop/output.txt`

`grep -lv '© 2013 copyright' ~/Folder/*`